# OpenApi arrays and nested objects validation

Tags: java, spring, openapi

I'm using OpenApi specification, this is an example of code that generates the class:

```
CreateUsersRequest:
      required:
        - userIds
      type: object
      properties:
        userIds:
          uniqueItems: true
          minItems: 1
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            format: uuid
```

I want to prohibit sending the following request:

```
{
  "userIds": [
    ""
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "userIds": [
    null
  ]
}
```

In case I used `javax.validation` it would look like:

```
@NotNull 
private List<@NotEmpty UUID> userIds;
```

Is there any ways to do the same using `api.yml` file ?

Comment: Where exactly (on which side) do you want to prohibit invalid inputs? Are you are sending requests from Swagger UI and you want it to reject inputs that don't match your OpenAPI definition? Or do you want to have these validations on the server side (e.g. in the server code generated by Swagger Codegen) or middleware? Please elaborate. Different tools (clients vs servers vs middleware) may or may not support such validations.

Comment: yea, I send requests from swagger UI and I want it to be validated on server side, ideally, through javax.validation, if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

As indicated [in the documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#null):

> OpenAPI 3.0 does not have an explicit `null` type as in JSON Schema, but you
> can use `nullable: true` to specify that the value may be `null`. Note that
> `null` is different from an empty string `""`.

To prevent the empty string you could provide a `pattern` regex.

Please, try the following:

```yaml
CreateUsersRequest:
      required:
        - userIds
      type: object
      properties:
        userIds:
          uniqueItems: true
          minItems: 1
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            format: uuid
            nullable: false
            pattern: ^[a-z|\-]+$
```

Please, test the code carefully, I realized you used `format: uuid`, so I am not absolutely confident about the combination of `format` and `pattern`.

If necessary, you could try providing your own `uuid` type. For example:

```yaml
Uuid:
    type: string
    pattern: '^[\da-f]{8}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{12}$'
    nullable: false
```

And:

```yaml
CreateUsersRequest:
      required:
        - userIds
      type: object
      properties:
        userIds:
          uniqueItems: true
          minItems: 1
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Uuid"
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I still can send both requests without any validation errors

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am sorry to hear that it didn't work properly. Please, could you try without the definition `format: uuid`?

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible workaround, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Without `format: uuid` it doesn't work as well. Yea, I can create my own type, but I need to use existing UUID

Comment: You are welcome mate, I am sorry for hadn't been of more help. Please, try reviewing your generator configuration, maybe it could give you some options that might be of help with the issue.